# encode tuple (memory) for exporting

Tags: python, csv

I have a list with different values. It looks like this:

```
data = [
('Column1', 'Column2'),
('myFirstNovel', 'myAge'),
('mySecondNovel', 'myAge2'),
('myThirdNovel', 'myAge3'),
('myFourthNovel', 'myAge4')
]
```

I'm getting encoding errors when I'm writing the data to csv and thus want to encode the data before exporting. So I tried this:

```
[[all.encode('utf-8') for all in items] for items in data]
```

Now this doesn't really solve my problem to begin with (the data gets filled with \xe2\x80\x94\xc2\xa0 and other stuff). But main thing is it takes ages and my python pretty much crashes.

Is there a better method or should I just change export method?

(using csv tool and writerows right now)

Comment: How big of a list are we talking about? Also, might be helpful to include sample data that contains the unicode strings instead of ordinary string...

Comment: Could you include a little more of your code so we can see the writerows call in context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using python 2.X you can use following `unicode_writer` class which python suggests in it's documentation:

```
class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)
```

And in python 3.X you can simply pass your encoding to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#open) function.